# Scala how to restore generics type in foreach

Tags: scala, generics

I have two classes with some data members like this:

```
class MyInfo {
   private val myId: String
   private val time: DateTime
   private val solution: Long
   private val banner: Int
}

Class HisInfo {
   private val id: String
   private val solution: Long
   private val banner: Int
}
```

As you can see these two classes share two members, and in my real project they share more. I need to save them into hbase and designed a class like this:

```
sealed trait Element[T] {
  def serialize(value: T)(implicit val helper: Helper[T]): Array[Byte]
  def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte])(implicit val helper: Helper[T]): T
}

case object LongElement extends Element[Long] {...}
case object IntElement extends  Element[Int] {...}

class Info {
 protected val data: Map[Element[_], Any] = new mutable.Map[Element[_], Any]()
}

class MyInfo extends Info {
  val elements = List(LongElement, IntLement)
  def saveToHBase = {
   elements.foreach { e =>
     val v = e.serialize(data(e))
     // do sth with v
   }
  }
```

In fact I have defined implementations of Helper[Int] and Helper[Long], but the compiler complains that it can not find implicit value for parameter Helper[_1]. Can someone help me to design these classes?

Comment: Have you defined the `Helper[Int]` and `Helper[Long]` as implicit values which are accessible in the scope where you call `e.serialize`?

Comment: Is there deinitely unique common field of each type with corresponding `Helper` or there need additional identification by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In fact I have defined implementations of Helper[Int] and Helper[Long], but the compiler complains that it can not find implicit value for parameter Helper[_1].

Well, consider what would happen if `elements` included an `Element[String]` (or some other type for which you have no implicit `Helper`). Given the type of `elements`, the compiler can't know it doesn't.

I think that if you need a `Helper` for all methods of `Element` anyway, you should just make it a part of the type:

```
sealed trait Element[T] {
  val helper: Helper[T] // or def if you want to put it in the companion object
  def serialize(value: T): Array[Byte]
  def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): T
}
```

or

```
sealed abstract class Element[T](implicit val helper: Helper[T]) {
  def serialize(value: T): Array[Byte]
  def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): T
}
```

At least in most situations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks like work for [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)
Cool thing about shapeless, it can convert your class to list like structure named [`HList`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists).
Scala ordinary collections like `List` should drop information about elements to bring them to common type.
`HList` could save type of each elements, while providing `List`-like functionality

Lets define your type with their common fields in separate type

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

class Common(
              val solution: Long,
              val banner: Int
            )

class MyInfo(
              myId: String,
              time: DateTime,
              solution: Long,
              banner: Int
            ) extends Common(solution, banner)

class HistInfo(
                id: String,
                solution: Long,
                banner: Int
              ) extends Common(solution, banner)
```

Now lets define something looks like serialization:

```
trait Helper[T] extends (T => Array[Byte])

implicit object longHelper extends Helper[Long] {
  def apply(x: Long) = 0 to 7 map (i => (x >> (i * 8)).toByte) toArray
}

implicit object intHelper extends Helper[Int] {
  def apply(x: Int) = 0 to 3 map (i => (x >> (i * 8)).toByte) toArray
}
```

Now something interesting. We'll create special object that could  convert your `Common` type to special `HList` which contains every value preserving it's type information and statically-saved string with field name:

```
import shapeless._
val lgen = LabelledGeneric[Common]
```

Next we define special function-like thing to map over such `HList`. It would find known `implicit Helper` and tie its result with corresponding field name:

```
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType

object serialized extends Poly1 {
  implicit def serialize[K <: Symbol, T]
  (implicit helper: Helper[T], key: Witness.Aux[K])
   = at[FieldType[K, T]](field => key.value.name -> helper(field))
}
```

Now we define some user of this function:

```
def extractMap(x: Common): Map[String, Seq[Byte]] =
  lgen.to(histInfo).map(serialized).toList.toMap.mapValues(_.toSeq)
```

You could verify you function is working:

```
val histInfo = new HistInfo("123", 12, 3)
println(extractMap(histInfo))
```

will print

> Map(solution -> WrappedArray(12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), banner ->
>   WrappedArray(3, 0, 0, 0))

Comment: Thanks but the solution seems to complicated and I guess it uses a lot of reflection, which may significantly harm the performance.

Comment: @Liu Renjie  No. It does not use reflection at all. Shapeless built on macros + impicits